# Why can't the console find my variable?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I know this code is long. Sorry, but I don't sacrifice space for readability. When I test this code the console gives me this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: useranswer
    doMath
    onclick
```

[image]

This is a quiz that can be emailed automatically by pressing my "Email Quiz" button.

Each variable with the nomenclature of "a**" is the boolean state of a radio input. I am checking the value of each of them to get the users answer on each question. Then I compare it to the correct answer and increment score if the answers match.

I also have some issues with the email quiz function... I'm not sure what the issue is.

Any insight on these issues?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<!--========================================================================-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function doMath()
    {   
        //Score

        var score = 0;

        // arrays to store answers, and user submited answers.
        var answer = new Array();
        var userAnswer = new Array();

        // Quiz answers:

        answer[0] = "e";
        answer[1] = "b";

        var a11 = document.getElementById('answer1-1').checked;
        var a12 = document.getElementById('answer1-2').checked;
        var a13 = document.getElementById('answer1-3').checked;
        var a14 = document.getElementById('answer1-4').checked;
        var a15 = document.getElementById('answer1-5').checked;

        var a21 = document.getElementById('answer2-1').checked;
        var a22 = document.getElementById('answer2-2').checked;
        var a23 = document.getElementById('answer2-3').checked;
        var a24 = document.getElementById('answer2-4').checked;
        var a25 = document.getElementById('answer2-5').checked;


        // checks users answer for first question:
        if(a11){
            useranswer[0] = "a";
        }
        else if(a12){
            useranswer[0] = "b";
        }
        else if(a13){
            useranswer[0] = "c";
        }
        else if(a14){
            useranswer[0] = "d";
        }
        else{
            useranswer[0] = "e";
        }

        // checks users answer for second question:
        if(a11){
            useranswer[1] = "a";
        }
        else if(a12){
            useranswer[1] = "b";
        }
        else if(a13){
            useranswer[1] = "c";
        }
        else if(a14){
            useranswer[1] = "d";
        }
        else{
            useranswer[1] = "e";
        }

        //adds up score:

        if(userAnswer[0] == answer[0]){
            score++;
        }

        if(userAnswer[1] == answer[1]){
            score++;
        }

        emailQuiz(score);
        console.log("doMath is working");
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    </script>
    <script>
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function emailQuiz(score)
    {
        var test = "\n\n You scored " + score + "/2 on the test.";
        window.open('mailto: noah.gary394@topper.wku.edu'
                        + '?subject= quiz answers' 
                        + '&body=  Your quiz results:' + escape(test));

        console.log("emailQuiz is working");
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    </script>
<!--========================================================================-->
</head>

    <button type="button" onclick="doMath();emailQuiz();">Email Quiz</button>

</body>
<!--========================================================================-->
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables in JavaScript are case-sensitive.

```
userAnswer != useranswer
```

This might not appear obvious however because JavaScript will automatically hoist any non `var`ed varible to the global namespace on it's first assignment.

Comment: I used to think that this is what makes JavaScript a bad language to write large projects in, but the `'use strict';` directive helps catch bugs like this (by forcing an var before any assignment, among other helpful things).